# Jquery Validation All Errors shows in one alert box only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, alert

I have a form where I can do jquery validation in one by one show error in an alert box.

I have required to show all validation error messages into one alert box for all those required fields (single or multiple fields) and not repeat the alert box display one-time only.

Is this possible?

example :

[image]

Here! the Issue

```
  <form id="myform" action="post">
      <input type="text" name="email" />
      <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" />
  </form>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var allerror="";
      $('#myform').validate({ // Jquery Validation
          onclick: false,
          onkeyup: false,
          rules: {
              email: {
                  required: true,
                  email: true
              },
              name: {
                  required: true,
                  minlength: 5
              }

          },
          messages: {
                         email: {
                                 required: "The Email is required!"
                         },
                         name: {
                                 required: "The name is required!"
                         }
                    },
                    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                allerror += error.text();
                                alert(allerror);
                    }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `errorPlacement` use `invalidHandler` as follow:

```
  invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
  var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
  if (errors) {
    if (validator.errorList.length > 0) {
        for (x=0;x<validator.errorList.length;x++) {
            errors += validator.errorList[x].message;
        }
    }
    alert(errors);
  }
}
```

Edit : 
If you dont want html labels for errors this should work :

```
           errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
              return false;
            },
```

Comment: Ohh! This is best! but little one issue after alert box, those errors shows after the input element into HTML also. is it possible not show there, show in alert only

Comment: I appreciate so much for your help! Thank a lot